# Connecting Laravel backend code to a localhost and then to remote host to use it in an android app

Tags: android, laravel, callback, localhost, web-hosting

I am new to backend stuff/logic so from the laravel i have to get a callback url that is posted as body param to the server and would be able to receive a response from the server but the issue is getting the url. Any Assistane...

Comment: i think you need to add in an example.

what server request, what request is expected etc

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would need to create a route in the `/routes/web.php`

Something like this:

```
Route::get('your-webhook-callback', function () {

    $result = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // do something with $result

});
```

Then your url would be something like 'http://yourdomain.com/your-webhook-callback'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the laravel backeend code as API .. i would recommend you to use api.php file to write your routes. `/routes/api.php`
suppose you have route like this

```
Route::get('all-categories', function(){
 //logic here
});
```

Now you can access this API on localhost on  this url `127.0.0.1:8000/api/all-categories`

and one more thing .. you can host your project in virtual host. check this link .[laravel virtual host](https://weblizar.com/blog/how-setup-virtual-host-for-laravel-xampp-wamp/)
and then you can access your website from android too .. just you need to be connected on same wifi and use you Laptop ip to access the routes in your android .like `197.168.xx.xxx/api/all-catgeories`
if you dont host project in virtual environment you can host your laravel project in public ip . `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`